# File attachment in CakePHP

Tags: file, email, cakephp

I have `logo.png` image in `webroot/img/` as follows:
[image]

I want to import it in my email body as follows:

```
 $Email->template('welcomeReseller')
                ->emailFormat('html')
                ->from(array($from => $cus_name))
                ->attachments(array(
                    array(
                        'file' => $this->webroot . 'img/logo.png',
                        'mimetype' => 'image',
                        'contentId' => '12345'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'file' => $this->webroot . 'img/logo.png',
                        'mimetype' => 'image',
                        'contentId' => '123456'
                    ),
                    array(
                        'file' => $this->webroot . 'img/logo.png',
                        'mimetype' => 'image',
                        'contentId' => '1234567'
                    ),
                ))
                ->viewVars($email_data)
                ->to($tests)
                ->subject($subject);

        $Email->send($body);
```

However, I am getting `File not found: "/demo-home25_/img/logo.png"` error. This simple. file path is not correct. But whats wrong in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Request::$webroot` is neither necessarily a path to your `app/webroot` folder, nor is it a local filesystem path, it's a URL fragment that points to your applications root entry point, which usually is the servers document root, or the folder that contains the `app` folder, only with URL rewriting disabled it might point to the `webroot` folder, but still it would only be a URL fragment.

Use the path constants instead, they contain actual filesystem paths, like `WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS` (which also works in Cake 3.x), or `IMAGES` (which is deprecated though).

```
array(
    'file' => WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'logo.png',
    'mimetype' => 'image',
    'contentId' => '12345'
)
```

See also

- **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.7.7/lib/Cake/bootstrap.php**
- **https://github.com/cakephp/app/blob/3.1.2/config/paths.php**